# Remove unknown DC Offset from a non-periodic discrete time signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Is there some process that can determine / remove an unknown DC offset from a  non-periodic discrete time signal?

The signal in in question has a sample rate of 25Hz and has harmonics of interest between 0.25 and 3 Hz.

I have tried using highpass filters mixed results, first I used a  10th order guassian with Fc = 0Hz, this did a good job of removing the offset but it severly attenuated the AC aswell although it did leave the signal shape intact, next I used a 168th order equilripple with a stopband at 0Hz and passband at 0.25Hz, the phase shift was too severe and the signal shape too distorted, the distortion could probably be reduced if the pass-band was brought down to 0.1Hz but this would just further increase the phase shift which I need to keep to the very minimum.

Before and after applying  x - LPF(x), as suggested by Paul R

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend using a notch filter at DC and using `filtfilt` to make it zero phase.

```
a = [1 , -0.98]; b = [1,-1];

y = filtfilt(b,a,x);
```

The closer the second value of `a` gets to -1 the narrower your notch will be.

Comment: I need to do some more testing, but this appears to give really nice results!

Comment: Use `freqz(xcorr(b,b),xcorr(a,a))` to check frequency response of you filter. The `xcorr`s are Z-transform counterparts of `filtfilt`. Try different values of `a(2)` to see how wide/narrow your notch gets.

Comment: `filtfilt` does not give linear phase, but zero-phase, which means that any delay introduced by the filter is 'compensated back', so the output is not delayed (compared to the input). Linear phase is something else.

Answer (score 10):

A DC offset means that some constant value was added to the signal (the name originates from adding a DC voltage to an analog AC signal). If the DC component is really constant (and not changing really slowly), then you don't have to design some high-order (and potentially unstable) high-pass filters - you can just subtract the average of your signal from the signal - which is, of course, a high-pass filter as well (averaging is a type of a low-pass, and '1 minus the average' is high-apss) --- but a very simple one.

If, on the other hand, you have a reason to believe that the DC component is not really a DC, but rather an AC with very low frequency, then you'd better average segments of your signal and not the signal as a whole, which is the same as using a low-pass filter with impulse response which is shorter then the length of the signal. In this case you have to make some assumptions about the "DC" component.

Comment: The problem is that the signal consists of a constant DC offset and two signal components of interest, a low frequency component and a high frequency component which is superimposed on the former. Attempting to filter out DC distorts the low frequency component.

Comment: If you average on many cycles of the low frequency signal, its contribution to the average is zero since the positive and negative samples cancel each other, so no distortion should take place. Can you upload a signal as an example? It would help answering your question.

Comment: Depending on the offset the low frequency signals magnitude may never be negative and its in no way periodic so its contribution may not be zero. Iv added a graph to my question so you can get an idea of the nature of the signal.

Comment: No, it does not depend on the DC offset. For example, if your AC is [1,-1,1,-1] and the DC [5,5,5,5], the sum signal is [6,4,6,4], the average signal is [5,5,5,5] and if you subtract it you get the AC. It holds since averaging is linear, so average of sum is sum of averages --- the DC average is just the offset, the AC average is 0.

Comment: But arent you still assuming that the AC is periodic? (which it isn't)

Comment: Not really, I am only saying that any signal `Y` can be represented as a sum of 2 signals `Y_DC + Y_AC`, one constant (the DC) and another with average of zero (AC). By construction, if `Y_DC` is defined to be `Y_bar` (denotes the average of `Y`), then the average of `Y_AC` (which equals `Y - Y_bar`), is zero.

Comment: I really like this method. I use a variation of it all the time. The FFT assumes that what ever you are feeding it is periodic, it doesn't matter if it is periodic or not. The DC term (also defined as the average power of the signal) from the FFT will be approximately the mean of the signal (or so I have seen in all my uses of this method). Find the mean of the signal by either the way Itamar Katz described or looking at the spectral domain.

Comment: The DC term is **exactly** the mean of the signal frame, not approximately. If you take the definition `Xk = 1/N * sum over n[Xn * exp(i*n*Wk)]`, and plug in for `k=0` the frequency `Wk=0`, you get the average.

Comment: If your low frequency component does not average to zero, even over the long term, then it contains some DC.  Since the DC of the offset and the DC in the low frequency component are mixed, there is no way to separate them and remove just the offset without some extra information or assumptions.  Maybe some sort of non-linear pattern recognizer that says "this is a flat spot" and subtracts that from everything nearby.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than implementing a high pass filter directly (which can be rather tricky for very low frequencies - you end up with a large number of coefficients and various issues with stability and passband ripple etc), you might instead want to consider implementing a low pass filter which will give you an estimate of the DC offset value, and then subtract this filtered offset from your signal, i.e. rather than:

```
y = HPF(x)
```

do this:

```
y = x - LPF(x)
```

The low pass filter can probably just be quite a simple filter with a relatively small number of terms. The big advantage of this implementation is that your higher frequency components should not have any unwanted artefacts due to phase, ripple, etc, since all you are doing is subtracting an almost stationary DC value from the samples.

The only potential downside is that if the DC offset is large you may have quite a long initial settling time before the estimate of the DC offset is accurate (although this is also true of any other implementation such as a direct high pass filter of course). If you have any *a priori* knowledge of what the offset value is likely to be (e.g. if it doesn't change very much from run to run, and you know the value from the previous run) then you can use this to optimise the settling time, by initialising the LPF state variables to a suitable value rather than 0.

Comment: I tried using an LPF as you suggested but its not having the desired effect, I tested a dozen different LPFs, the best was a 50 term guassian with Fc = 0.0001Hz and Alpha = 1.1. The problem is that the lower frequency harmonic of interest is being distorted. Iv added a before and after graph to my question

Comment: Can you plot the output of the LPF in addition to the input and output signal ? It would be interesting to see when and by how much it's varying. I still think the basic idea is sound but getting the filter right may well be tricky - I'd be inclined to try designing it by hand.

Comment: I added the plots. As you can see the LPF captures most of the low frequency signal that I don't want to filter out.

Comment: OK - the LPF evidently doesn't have the right response - if you have a more or less constant DC component then the LPF output should converge slowly to this value and then pretty much stay there.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, to remove a DC offset, you can simply subtract the mean.  Your signal does not need to be periodic, but it does need to be long enough to get a good estimate of the DC component.

If you still wish to go with a filtering approach, you can eliminate the severe distortion due to phase lag by using [`filtfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/filtfilt.html).  This function filters your timeseries once in the forwards direction and then once in the reverse direction, so that phase distortions cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

You can design a symmetric FIR filter as the low-pass filter that estimates the DC and then subtract the output from your input signal. This filter has constant group-delay.