# Aligning two data sets in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I want to develop some python code to align datasets obtained by different instruments recording the same event.

As an example, say I have two sets of measurements:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define some data
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'TIME':[1.1, 2.4, 3.2, 4.1, 5.3],\
                      'VALUE':[10.3, 10.5, 11.0, 10.9, 10.7],\
              'ERROR':[0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'TIME':[0.9, 2.1, 2.9, 4.2],\
                      'VALUE':[18.4, 18.7, 18.9, 18.8],\
              'ERROR':[0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4]})

# Plot the data      
plt.errorbar(data1.TIME, data1.VALUE, yerr=data1.ERROR, fmt='ro')
plt.errorbar(data2.TIME, data2.VALUE, yerr=data2.ERROR, fmt='bo')
plt.show()
```

The result is plotted here:
[image]

What I would like to do now is to align the second dataset (data2) to the first one (data1). i.e. to get this:
[image]

The second dataset must be shifted to match the first one by subtracting a constant (to be determined) from all its values. All I know is that the datasets are correlated since the two instruments are measuring the same event but with different sampling rates.

At this stage I do not want to make any assumptions about what function best describes the data (fitting will be done after alignment).

I am cautious about using means to perform shifts since it may produce bad results, depending on how the data is sampled. I was considering taking each data2[TIME_i] and working out the shortest distance to data1[~TIME_i]. Then minimizing the sum of those. But I am not sure that would work well either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a good method to use? I looked at [mlpy](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/) but it seems to only work on 1D arrays.

Thanks.

Comment: Should be migrated to http://stats.stackexchange.com/  This is not the place to iterate through all possible ways to align two data sets.  Once you know what you want, come back here for a way to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

You can substract the mean of the difference: `data2.VALUE-(data2.VALUE - data1.VALUE).mean()`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define some data
data1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': [1.1, 2.4, 3.2, 4.1, 5.3],
    'VALUE': [10.3, 10.5, 11.0, 10.9, 10.7],
    'ERROR': [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2],
})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': [0.9, 2.1, 2.9, 4.2],
    'VALUE': [18.4, 18.7, 18.9, 18.8],
    'ERROR': [0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4],
})

# Plot the data
plt.errorbar(data1.TIME, data1.VALUE, yerr=data1.ERROR, fmt='ro')
plt.errorbar(data2.TIME, data2.VALUE-(data2.VALUE - data1.VALUE).mean(),
             yerr=data2.ERROR, fmt='bo')
plt.show()
```

[image: aligned error bars]

Another possibility is to subtract the mean of each series

Comment: I am a bit cautious about implementing something like that because it will not always provide a good solution. Consider the following situation: data1 and data2 are both sampling a gaussian distribution but the data1 corresponds to measurements obtained mainly at the wings of the distribution and data2 around the peak. Using the means to perform the shifts might not give the best results in this case. I was thinking of binning both datasets in x and working out distances to the nearest neighbours. Then minimizing the sum of those. But I am not sure that would work either.

Comment: @Hooloovoo: The only specification you gave was the two graphs, and this answer is mathematically reasonable and looks exactly like what you say you wanted (so +1).  If you knew about the mean solution and didn't like it, you should have said that in your initial question.  It takes time to answer questions, and it's a waste to do so just so you can say that you already knew about the obvious answer and are looking for something more subtle.  An error weighted mean is possible, but if you knew that's what you wanted, then ask for it.

Comment: Thanks @Hooloovoo I would have said the same. If you ask for it, do so in a new question and probably at stats@SE.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the offset of the average and subtract that from every value. If you do this  for every value they should align relatively well. This would assume both dataset look relatively similar, so it might not work the best.

Although this question is not Matlab related, you might still be interested in this:
[Remove unknown DC Offset from a non-periodic discrete time signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994020/remove-unknown-dc-offset-from-a-non-periodic-discrete-time-signal)